# Does Git has built-in SSH server?

Tags: ssh, git

I'm trying to setup Git's remote SSH server to access this using SSH, but I haven't found any info how to make this.

So, does Git has built-in SSH tools to establish such connection to use this "right from box"? Or there it's not and I should to use 3d-party ones?

Comment: You'll find this link helpful: [Git - Setting up the Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, git doesn't have an SSH server. Why should it? It uses the system standard SSH system.